# Are huge pages used in allocating work_mem in PostgreSQL?

Tags: linux, postgresql

As long as I know, PostgreSQL can use huge pages in allocating shared_mem.
But can it use huge pages to allocate work_mem?

Comment: `work_mem` is typically something in the "high MB" area, which wouldn't really profit from huge pages. If I understand them correctly, they have an advantage for a few (very) large memory blocks, not for many "small" ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-HUGE-PAGES) says about `huge_page` parameter:

> Note that this setting only affects the main shared memory area.
>   Operating systems such as Linux, FreeBSD, and Illumos can also use
>   huge pages (also known as “super” pages or “large” pages)
>   automatically for normal memory allocation, without an explicit
>   request from PostgreSQL. On Linux, this is called “transparent huge
>   pages” (THP). That feature has been known to cause performance
>   degradation with PostgreSQL for some users on some Linux versions, so
>   its use is currently discouraged (unlike explicit use of huge_pages).

Comment: In other words, no, because you always want to disable transparent huge pages.